# Eclipse IDE crashes on Windows 10 before setting up workspace

Tags: eclipse, crash, windows-10

I have the Eclipse IDE on my Windows 10, 64 bit, computer. When I open it, it crashes before opening the work space setup screen, and makes an error file in it's configuration file. The file says:

```
!SESSION 2017-09-29 19:39:18.799 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20110210-1200
java.version=9
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -clean

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 4 0 2017-09-29 19:39:19.975
    !MESSAGE 
    !STACK 0
    org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.200.v20100503 [1]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1,J2SE-1.4
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1317)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1301)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1067)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:337)

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-09-29 19:39:20.003
    !MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.200.v20100503.jar/ was not resolved.

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-09-29 19:39:20.021
    !MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-09-29 19:39:20.022
    !MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.200.v20100503 [1] was not resolved.
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 2 0 2017-09-29 19:39:20.022
    !MESSAGE Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1,J2SE-1.4

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-09-29 19:39:20.055
    !MESSAGE Application error
    !STACK 1
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
```

I have tried many solutions to similar problems, but none of them worked.
Any and all help would greatly be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using an old version of Eclipse with Java 9. This old version of Eclipse does not understand Java 9 and fails to start. You will have to change to Java 8 to run this version of Eclipse.

Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a) due for release on 11 October (2017) is the first release of Eclipse that fully supports Java 9.

Comment: Will this package work?
 http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/oxygen1

Comment: Current releases of Eclipse Oxygen have to be modified to work with Java 9 as described in the [Eclipse Wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Configure_Eclipse_for_Java_9)

Comment: I was having problems with eclipse oxygen, and I saw another win 10 problem solved by going to older eclipse versions. Should I get Java 8 or modify eclipse oxygen?

Comment: Never mind, I got bored and got eclipse oxygen. Then I followed the wiki link and it works! Thanks very much! :)